# An example that $f,g$ is Riemann integrable on $[a,b]$, the range of $f$ is $[a,b]$, but $g\circ f$ is not Riemann integrable.

Tags: calculus

I can easily find an example that $f,g$ is Riemann integrable but $g\circ f$ is not integrable, put $f(x)=R(x)=\begin{cases} \dfrac{1}{q}, & x=\dfrac{p}{q},\\ 0,& x\in\mathbf{Q}^{C}\end{cases}, g(x)=\begin{cases} 1, & x\neq 0,\\ 0, & x=0\end{cases}$, for example, then $g(f(x))$ is the Dirichlet function.

However, if we add the condition

> the range of $f$ is $[a,b]$,

this is not so trival. I presume, we could construct a function $f$ with  Intermediate Value Property but non-continuous, then search for an appropriate $g$.

Comment: What is the range of $f$ ? $f: [a;b] \to \mathbb{R}$ or $f:I\subset\mathbb{R}\to [a;b]$.

Comment: @Quantic_Solver I presume, $f: I\subset [a,b]\to[a,b]$, or simply $\{f(x)\mid x\in[a,b]\}=[a,b]$.

Answer (score 1):

The classic example, as you have stated, involves a Riemann function and a jump discontinuity at zero. To preserve these key features, we could define $f:[0,1]\to[0,1]$
$$
f(x)=\begin{cases}0 & x=1 \\ 1-x & 0<x<1 \\ 1 & x=1\end{cases}
$$
This is a bijection which still causes $f\circ g$ to behave like the Dirichlet function. The discontinuity (and thus non-monotonicity) is necessary, since the composition with a continuous function will always be Riemann integrable.

Answer (score 0):

Why not define:
$$f : [-1, 1] \to [-1, 1] : x \mapsto \begin{cases} 2x + 1 & \text{if } -1 \le x < 0 \\ \frac{1}{q} & \text{if } x \in [0, 1] \text{ and } x = \frac{p}{q} \text{ with } p, q \in \mathbb{Z} \text{ and } \operatorname{gcd}(p, q) = 1 \\ 0 & \text{if } x \in [0, 1] \setminus \mathbb{Q}\end{cases},$$
and $g$ as before, defined over $[-1, 1]$.

Then, if $g \circ f$ is Riemann integrable, then  $g \circ f|_{[0, 1]}$ ought to be Riemann integrable, but it too is just the Dirichlet function.

Comment: Pretty good answer, but I wonder can we find a more non-integrable one? I mean, an example that $g\circ f$ is not integrable in any sub-interval $[c,d]\subset[a,b]$.